# All Images of my Expo React Native App disappeared

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile, expo

I was trying to solve : Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered

Uninstalled react-native-gesture-handler, react-native-reanimated, node_modules and package-lock before reinstalling everything (npm & npx expo)

Now i can start the app but all my local images disappeared

That's how i define an image : <Image source={require('../Images/infirmière.png')} style={styles.img}/> (All images are still in the folder Images)

Never happened to me before, does someone know what's going on ?

**[EDIT]**

Found the answer. I just forgot to update the dependencies after updating expo SDK

**[EDIT]**

Answer (score 0):

Please define "Dissapeared". The app loads and the images just dont show? Or are you getting an error that the image(s) cannot be found? Please also include code that shows your package.json, how you are importing the image component and the styles.img object.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The app loads and the images don't show

Package.json

```js
{
  "name": "gestioninventaire",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^18.7.3",
    "@react-native/js-polyfills": "^0.74.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^6.6.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.12",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.20",
    "@rneui/base": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "@rneui/themed": "^4.0.0-rc.7",
    "expo": "^50.0.8",
    "expo-font": "~11.1.1",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~12.1.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.4.4",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-pager-view": "6.1.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.20.0",
    "react-native-svg": "13.4.0",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.5.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.14.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.6.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

From one of my files :

`import { View, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView, Text, TextInput, StatusBar, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';`

```js
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    View:{
        flex: 1,
        paddingTop: StatusBar.currentHeight,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    img:{
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
      },
      
      //following style
      
     })
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try using this format:

```
<Image
  source={{uri: 'asset:/app_icon.png'}}
  style={{width: 40, height: 40}}
/>
```

Just make sure the image is in the assets folder and actually exists because this format will not throw an error if it cannot find the image.

If you would like to stick to require(), try removing the style prop. Like so:

```
<Image source={require('../Images/infirmière.png')}/>
```

The require() function uses the width and height of the image itself.

> "Note that image sources required this way include size (width,
> height) info for the Image. If you need to scale the image dynamically
> (i.e. via flex), you may need to manually set {width: undefined,
> height: undefined} on the style attribute."
> [1](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images)

Also note that special characters in a file path, including accented letters, can sometimes cause issues in React Native and other programming languages.If you’re dealing with file paths that contain special characters, you might need to encode the path like so:

```
const path = 'file:///test/@#$%/0.png';
const encodedPath = 'file://' + path.replace('file://', '').split('/').map((p) => encodeURIComponent(p)).join('/');
```